# Can machine learning methods be somehow helpful in solving differential equations?

Tags: machine-learning, references, differential-equations

I noted that regression task in machine learning is somehow related to solving differential equations approximately - both are trying to approximate unknown function.

Then, my question is: Can ML be somehow helpful in solving differential equations?

Comment: This looks too vague to be answerable. Could you provide references and/or a specific question?

Comment: Yes, I can. I was motivated also by this article: http://www.is.tuebingen.mpg.de/fileadmin/user_upload/files/publications/sysid06-final_3640[0].pdf

Comment: I don't see the relevance: that paper constructs a differential equation to help solve a ML problem.  Isn't the whole point that we can then turn to *other* methods of solving the differential equation? An approximate solution to a DE is not "trying to approximate [an] unknown function"; rather, it is obtaining numerical values of a function that is *known* but given in an indirect fashion (the DE itself).

Comment: Check out Physics Informed Neural Nets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics-informed_neural_networks

Comment: @whuber Bayesians have interesting things to say about the validity of differential equation solving as the objective of statistical inference, i.e. "In a Bayesian approach, f(x) [the function which is the solution of the differential equation evaluated at an arbitrary point x] is random simply because it is numerically unknown. It has a known algebraic expression, but we do not know the numerical value of f(x) for any x until we actually calculate it. " O'Hagan '91, introduction of https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/037837589190002V

Comment: @John Thank you.  The distinction I am trying to point out is between some *definite* function, conceived of perhaps as a realization of a random function, and the "approximate solution" referred to in this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Absolutely!

Here is information on the "shooting method". ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method))

For much harder problems than the example given, the "root finding" takes more work.  It is useful to stick some machine learning on top of the output in order to determine which initial conditions are appropriate for the solution of interest.

**EDIT**:

Neural Networks (NN) are used to (profoundly) improve computation time for combustion.  The networks are trained on the thermo-chemical model and approximate the chemical reactions so that instead of solving (insane) complexity coupled fluid-dynamic and chemistry differential equations, the numeric solver has a reduced set of solves, and the NN with its very short run time, fills in the gaps "well enough".  [Here is a link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0307904X11005129).  [Here is another](http://www.unizar.es/dopazo/PUBS/Refereed%20Journals%20CD/42CombFlame.pdf).

**EDIT 2**:
See physics-informed neural networks.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hKHl68Fdpq4

Answer (score 2):

[I believe so](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=differential%20equations%20gaussian%20processes), Archembau, Cornford, Opper, Shawe-Taylor, Girolami, Lawrence and Rattray are all excellent researchers in machine learning, so these would probably be good places to start.